# How to RNG and delay bash script pressing RETURN for an autotyper script

Tags: bash, random, delay, xdotool

Currently I'm using a bash script that automatically types out a phrase, but I wonder how to RNG the sleep counter for example to like 1800-1900 seconds. If possible I'd also like to know how to make the script delay pressing RETURN. Thanks.

this is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function autotype_loop()  {
xdotool key space
xdotool type "Text here"
xdotool key Return
sleep 1810
autotype_loop
}
autotype_loop
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin variable for this use-case:

```
'RANDOM'
     Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0
     and 32767 is generated.
```

If you whant to generate a random variable x between 1800-1900 you can use arithmetic expressions:

```
x=$(( 1800 + $RANDOM * 100 / 32767 ))
```